# Image first pixel is always 0

Tags: java, android, image

I'm using the Android Camera2 to get video frames of YUV420 format. I only need the Y(luminance) values (to get a grayscale image). I'm extracting them from the object (**Image** frame) like this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = frame.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] luminance = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(luminance);
```

But when I print them to see the pixel values, the first pixel (luminance[0]) is always 0. The rest seem to be fine, example:

```
luminance[0]: 0
luminance[1]: 109
luminance[2]: 109
luminance[3]: 108
luminance[4]: 110
luminance[5]: 111
luminance[6]: 109
```

Why is that? Am I extracting the luminance wrong?

Comment: Your code looks correct to me

Comment: Maybe it's just the camera/sensor?